# I have method which is working fine,but when i return driver from method its showing following error?

Tags: maven, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, testng, integration-testing

```
public WebDriver init()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/pavan/eclipse-workspace/Utility/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://phptravels.com/demo");
    return driver;
}
```

[I am getting following error but if i executed code without return code is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PtBo.png)

Comment: Please add the error as text here. StackOverflow doesn't recommend promoting questions with details in images and your question is prone to downvoting..

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the code you posted. The problem is that your test suite is empty. No test with test annotation (@Test) is being triggered - so testNG is telling you there is nothing to test.

If your init method is part of the testing - just add the annotation:

```
@Test
public WebDriver init()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/pavan/eclipse-workspace/Utility/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://phptravels.com/demo");
    return driver;
}
```